# Insert conditionally on number of rows matching condition in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, unique, upsert

I have a table like this:

```
  create table if not exists features (
     username text not null,
     feature text not null,
     attributes text[] not null,

     primary key(username, feature)
  );
```

I want to insert a new feature for a user but only if they have less than 2 features currently in the table. I also want to update the feature's attributes if the user already has that feature in the table.

This is what I've got so far:

```
with f (username, feature, attributes, fcount) as (
    values (
        'bob', 'dashboard', '{"theme=dark"}'::text[], 
        (select count(*) from features where username = 'bob' and feature = 'dashboard')
    )
)
insert into features (
    username,
    feature,
    attributes
)
select username, feature, attributes 
from f 
where fcount < 2
on conflict (username, feature)
do update set attributes = excluded.attributes
;
```

When I run this three times with different feature names it adds three rows instead of 2.

```
username    feature     attributes
bob         dashboard   theme=dark
bob         dashboard1  theme=dark
bob         dashboard2  theme=dark
```

How can I achieve this? Is it possible to do this with a single insert query or do I need to use a transaction and multiple queries?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/dcc7c/2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem - the select list in brackets gives a tuple, not individual columns. Moreover, `attributes` in the values clause should be explicitly casted to `text[].` Also note the proper use of the special record `excluded` in the `on conflict` section.

```
with f (username, feature, attributes, fcount) as (
    values (
        'bob', 'dashboard', '{"theme=dark"}'::text[], 
        (select count(*) from features where username = 'bob')
    )
)
insert into features (
    username,
    feature,
    attributes
)
select username, feature, attributes 
from f 
where fcount < 2
on conflict (username, feature)
do update set attributes = excluded.attributes;
```

Comment: Thanks @klin! To be clear are you saying I don't need that final where clause?

Comment: Yes, find examples with `excluded` in [the documentation.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html)

Comment: I got around to testing the limit part of this and this doesn't prevent the record from being created. I changed the limit from 10 to 2 here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/dcc7c/13

Comment: Well, it's a logical mistake, you should count rows only for `username` and not for `feature`. See the updated answer.